# Symfony3 - Using LEFT or RIGHT with doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

From my names table containing values `id, firstName, lastName` I want to take out all rows, **but** from the `firstName` I just want the first letter.

I know I can make custom mySql query with doctrine but was wondering is there a more....well docrtine way to do such things (and other value select operations).

What could be the way to do it with solely doctrine?

An option to get the full string and then cut it in php is out of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for DQL Function substring(). If you're using query builder, You can do `$qb->expr()->substring(string, start,end)`. If I remember correctly, first character's position is 1 not 0.

Refer: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: But does it get data and then substring it, or the other way?
The real idea behind here is for a blog. It is ment to get the fist 50 characters of a huge text for a blog post list.
I want to avoid getting redundant data

Comment: It basically translates to SQL Function SUBSTR. So it's done on SQL Server  not in your application. if you are in doubt, dump SQL.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but after accepting the answer I found I cant get the operation to work properly.
Tried to use it like this:
` $qb->select("p")->from("AppBundle\Entity\Post", "p");`
        `$qb->expr()->substring('p.name', 1, 1);`
        `$query = $qb->getQuery();`

Yet it doesn't do anything with the text

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to use DQL Functions. They are part of SQL Statement. Also you can pass the entity alias in createQueryBuilder function(provided you're doing this in repository class). Your Query becomes `$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $query->select($query->expr()->substring('p.name',1,1).'AS name')
            ->distinct()
            ->addOrderBy('name','ASC');
        $query = $query->getQuery();` . Distinct and addOrderBy() are optional. but, if you have aliased a field, that's how you use them. Always dump SQL and check if your query is right.